# How can I add a legend to a plot with errorbars in the same color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a diagram with two data sets, one of which has error bars in y-direction. These should be labeled. How do I achieve that error bars, line and label for the first plot have the same color?
I included the corresponding plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [0,1,3,5,10]
b = [5,5,2,10,4]
c  = [5,5,1,1,1]
d = [1,1,2,3,4]

plt.plot(a, b, label = "b")
plt.plot(a, c,label ="c")

plt.legend(loc= "upper left")

plt.errorbar(a, b, d)

plt.xlabel("xlab")
plt.ylabel("ylab")
plt.show()
```

[image: The plot I receive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` class is useful for defining custom legends.

### Code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

x = [0,1,3,5,10]
y1 = [5,5,2,10,4]
y2  = [5,5,1,1,1]
e = [1,1,2,3,4]

# Define colours
c1 = "b"
c2 = "r"

plt.errorbar(x, y1, e, c=c1)
plt.plot(x, y2, c=c2)

plt.legend(
    loc="upper left",
    handles=[
        Line2D([], [], c=c1, label="b"),
        Line2D([], [], c=c2, label="c"),
    ]
)

plt.xlabel("xlab")
plt.ylabel("ylab")
plt.savefig("temp.png")
```

### Temp.png

[image]

Comment: matplotlib.org provides a tutorial for the work with legends. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this?

```
a = [0,1,3,5,10]
b = [5,5,2,10,4]
c = [5,5,1,1,1]
d = [1,1,2,3,4]


plt.plot(a, c,label ="c")

plt.errorbar(a, b, d, label='b')

plt.legend(loc= "upper left")


plt.xlabel("xlab")
plt.ylabel("ylab")
plt.show()
```

[image]